# Element is not longer attached to the DOM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My purpose is create list of elemnets and then click on it. For the first iteration loop works perfectly, it open first link. Then it failed.

My code is :

```
    hrefList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[contains(text(), 'כרטיס רופא')]")

    print("length of List is : " + str(len(hrefList)))

    for href in hrefList:
        print(href)
        href.click()
```

I get the next error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: 
Message: The element reference of <a> stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed
```

Comment: do you realize that if you will click on the link a new page will be loaded and something will change on the page and links might not exist on the page?? what's the case??

Comment: @KDD U tried???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes when element is not present in DOM. You have to come back to the main page and then click it

Try this code you will get a solution, This is java code

```
String URL="https://www.ida.org.il/?pageType=19&langId=1&paramIds=%2Con_321%2Con_322%2Con_354%2Con_355%2Con_320&scope=&parameterSearch=";
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(URL);
    List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'https://www.ida.org.il/?categoryId=96318&itemId')]"));
    System.out.println("Total links: "+links.size());
    for (int i=0;i<links.size();i++) {


     links.get(i).click();
     System.out.println(i
             +"Current URL is: "+driver.getCurrentUrl());
     driver.navigate().back();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     links=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'https://www.ida.org.il/?categoryId=96318&itemId')]"));
    }
```